# Batch insert in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, batch-insert

I am using a API's with lot's of calculation almost 100 database fields at the end with a big Foreach loop.

In every iteration i insert data in database. I want to insert data in once at the end (Batch Insert like in CodeIgniter).

Any body have idea how to insert all data at the end of iteration. instead of every iteration it insert row in database.

I want to insert  data at the end of loop. Any help or idea  appreciated.

Comment: that is exactly i also looking. ..

Comment: https://github.com/mavinoo/laravelBatch

Answer (score 38):

Use [`insert()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#inserts) method for bulk insertion. First, build an array with this structure:

```
$data = [
    ['name' => 'John', 'age' => 25],
    ['name' => 'Maria', 'age' => 31],
    ['name' => 'Julia', 'age' => 55],
];
```

Then insert the data using Eloquent model:

```
Model::insert($data);
```

Or using query builder:

```
DB::table('table_name')->insert($data);
```

Comment: Alexey Mezenin's answer should be marked as the solution

Comment: After insertion will able to get Autoincrement Id with response